How do I log the queries used by Feast for point in time joins
I have a Feast feature store setup with a Snowflake offline store, Snowflake registry and a DynamoDB online store. I am playing around with some feature store retrieval scenarios and would like to understand the queries Feast is using to retrieve historical data. How can I log or print these queries?

On the Snowflake side you can use the built-in Query History functions and views to retrieve the SQL and other execution information generated by Feast against your Offline Store.
You may also be able to adjust your Snowflake connection configuration to enable logging on the Python client side.
